# how to define text "variables" in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use Emacs for writing, not for coding. Is there an easy way, in Emacs or Emacs org-mode, to define a text string as a variable so that I can use it repeatedly?

Example: I created a template `invoice.org`. It would be cool to put a variable like `$CLIENTNAME` in the headers, in the table, on the cover page, in `#+TITLE:`, and in the thank you, use that as a template, and then quickly generate a new PDF for each new client by just adding a line at the beginning like `let $CLIENTNAME="Jane Doe"`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use Macros (see [the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-replacement.html))

You can define them by using

```
#+MACRO: clientname Jane Doe
```

and then call them by inserting `{{{clientname}}}` in the document where desired.

On export `{{{clientname}}}` will expand to `Jane Doe`.

Comment: That only works within Org-Mode.